# Transmission-daemon service spontaneously stops

Tags: services, centos, bittorrent, transmission

I've installed, configured and ran transmission-daemon on my CentOS 6 machine using

```
service transmission-daemon start
```

This works nicely, and I can see the web interface on `http://server.ip:9091` as I need to. The problem is, that several minutes later, it spontaneously stops. Never says anything, without warning or error message.

This happens even when I have no torrents active at all (as in, none on the list).

I have no idea what's wrong, and the error logs I thought of (which probably isn't much) show nothing.

How can I diagnose the causes for this? Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

### EDIT

```
After the suggestion Martin gave me, I got the log. It goes like this:
[03:07:02.182] Transmission 2.13 (11501) started (session.c:624)
[03:07:02.182] RPC Server Adding address to whitelist: 127.0.0.1 (rpc-server.c:789)
[03:07:02.182] RPC Server Serving RPC and Web requests on port 9091 (rpc-server.c:962)
[03:07:02.182] DHT Generating new id (tr-dht.c:384)
[03:07:02.182] Using settings from "/var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon" (daemon.c:483)
[03:07:02.182] Saved "/var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json" (bencode.c:1683)
[03:07:10.182] Port Forwarding State changed from "Not forwarded" to "???" (port-forwarding.c:95)
[03:07:18.188] Searching for web interface file "/var/lib/transmission/.local/share/transmission/web/index.html" (platform.c:526)
[03:07:18.188] Searching for web interface file "/usr/share/transmission/web/index.html" (platform.c:526)
[03:07:24.189] DHT Attempting bootstrap from dht.transmissionbt.com (tr-dht.c:241)
```

It hangs on that last one until it dies. Now I've looked into [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135178/transmission-remote-gui-setup-hangs-on-dht-attempting-to-bootstrap), but my settings file is already owned by `transmission`, and even changing the permissions on the file to `775` didn't seem to have any effects.

Any ideas?

Comment: I honestly don't have much clue where to look. If I'm missing any information on this question, please tell me and I'll edit it right away.

Answer (score 4):

I investigated similar problems a while ago, but on a Debian system.

Here's how i enabled logging. Since you run CentOS, you would need to adjust this a bit

```
sudo nano /etc/default/transmission-daemon
```

add to OPTIONS:

```
-e /var/log/transmission-daemon.log
```

create & give rights of logfile to transmission:

```
sudo touch /var/log/transmission-daemon.log
sudo chown debian-transmission:debian-transmission /var/log/transmission-daemon.log
sudo service transmission-daemon restart
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

i had this issue, turns out `transmission.log` had grown to over 7GB.

when i deleted it, everything went back to working as expected. i've created a cron to delete it on a schedule. hopefully that will keep it in check.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an error with transmission-daemon stopping when the main disk is full. It's a simple thing to overlook.